# Java 8 functional constructor from templated object

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, functional-programming, java-8

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), Java 8 u51.

I'm trying to create a method which will create instances of a passed object based on another method parameter. The prototype is simplified to

```
public <T> T test(Object param, T instance) {
    Constructor<?> constructor = instance.getClass().getConstructors()[0]; // I actually choose a proper constructor

    // eclipse reports "Unhandled exception type InvocationTargetException"
    Function<Object, Object> createFun = constructor::newInstance;

    T result = (T) createFun.apply(param);
    return result;
}
```

On line with `Function` declaration eclipse reports `Unhandled exception type InvocationTargetException` compiler error. I need the `Function` to later use in a stream.

I tried to add various  try/catch blocks, throws declarations, but nothing fixes this compiler error.

How to make this code work?

Comment: What do you think is the advantage of the `Function` detour over simply calling `newInstance` on the `Constructor`?

Comment: @Holger I was using `newInstance` on the `Constructor` in-stream and it produced the same message, so I created a SSCE like this. The function detour is actually necessary to keep a relatively readable `stream()` chain.

Comment: I see. So it was a bit oversimplified regarding the use case and a lambda expression as assylias has suggested should work. But what I’d like to know now, is, whether there is really a hard requirement regarding the resulting type being the exact type of `instance` (which might be a subclass of `T`), in other words whether resorting to Reflection is really necessary…

Comment: @Holger I could not find a reflectionless solution. The method is indeed used for many subclasses of T. I wanted a method with a clean definition but with a possibly ugly - but single - implementation. I ended up passing a `Class<T>` instead of an instance of T though.

Comment: Well, using a `Class` precludes the possibility that the result is a subclass of that class. If you have a known concrete type on the caller’s site, a construct like `Function<A,B> f=B::new;` should be possible. If the caller itself is generic, it doesn’t work that easy but it has to get the `Class` object from somewhere, hasn’t it? Maybe there is a Reflection-less solution, but that seems to be worth opening another question (with more information about the use case)…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't throw a checked exception from a lambda with a `Function` target type because its `apply` method does not throw an exception. So you need to make it into an unchecked exception, for example by wrapping it:

```
Function<Object, Object> createFun = o -> {
  try {
    return constructor.newInstance(o);
  } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
};
```

An alternative is to lead the compiler to think it's an unchecked exception, which produces a cleaner stack trace vs. the option above:

```
Function<Object, Object> createFun = o -> {
  try {
    return constructor.newInstance(o);
  } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    return uncheck(e);
  }
};
```

With the following utility method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <E extends Throwable, T> T uncheck(Throwable t) throws E {
  throw ((E) t);
}
```

Comment: You can throw a checked exception from a lambda. But not from a lambda which is supposed to implement Function, because Function.apply() doesn't throw a checked exception.

Comment: You could probably tighten up your `uncheck` method by introducing a `<T extends Throwable>` bound, so you don't have to do any sorts of cast.  You could also just perform your throw inside of the `uncheck` method, too; no need for two methods when you could just throw in one.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the Method Reference is to a Method with the Exceptions named in the compile time error. The single abstract Method `R apply(T t`
) in `java.util.Function`
does not throw these Exceptions. So there is a mismatch between the functional type of java.util.Function and the type of your Method-Reference.

Using a functional type with a matching method works ... for example :

```
    interface MyFunction<T,R> {
        /**
         * Applies this function to the given argument.
         *
         * @param t the function argument
         * @return the function result
         */
        R apply(T t) throws  Throwable;

    }

    public <T> T test(Object param, T instance) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
           IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Constructor<?> constructor = instance.getClass().getConstructors()[0]; // I actually choose a proper constructor

        // eclipse reports "Unhandled exception type InvocationTargetException"
            MyFunction<Object,Object> createFun = constructor::newInstance;

        T result = (T) createFun.apply(param);
        return result;
    }
```