# java 8 handling custom exception when using Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there any support for handling custom exception inside the Collectors.toMap. 
I am calling a method inside the Collector.toMap which throws MyException. Can it be rethrown in the calling function **pupulateValues()**? For demonstration I used below code to rethrow MyException but couldn't get through. My objective is to handle MyException in main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        pupulateValues();
    } catch (MyException e) {
           // do something
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void pupulateValues() throws MyException{
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("asdf", "asdf");
    map.put("ss", "fff");
    map.put("aaaaaa", "aaaaaaa");

    Map<String,String> map2=map.entrySet().stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(),entry-> {
                try {
                    return getCert(entry.getValue());
                } catch (MyException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    throw new MyException();
                }}));

}

static String getCert(String val) throws MyException {
    if(val == null) {
        throw new MyException("Some exception");
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. make `MyException` an unchecked exception
2. wrap it: `catch (MyException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`
3. trick the compiler:

   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757456/829571
   - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31470959/829571
   - https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL#orgjooqlambdaunchecked

Comment: 4. Use a for loop than streams